# Sometimes Qt thread is not started. How to forcefully or detect if it has been started

Tags: pyqt5, qthread

I have questions :

My program uses several threads to read data from sensors through GPIO. But sometimes one thread don't want to start. I know it by placing debug message in *run()* method at the beginning of it.

I try to increase thread prio. The current setting is *QThread.HighPriority*. But still, sometimes it has not been started.

Is there any way to force a thread to start when it has not been started for a duration of time?

this is a piece a code that wraps a class that has run() method and wraps it in the thread and starts it.

```
def move_and_start_thread(_service, priority=QThread.HighPriority):
    thread = QThread()
    _service.moveToThread(thread)
    thread.started.connect(_service.run)
    thread.start(priority)
    return thread
```

or maybe a better solution to make sure a thread is always executed by apps.

many thanks for any ideas.

Comment: i find unlikely that a thread wouldn't start and others do, unless there are functions that block access to he I/O and/or there's some kind of synchronous/serial command requirement. Please provide a [mre].

Comment: What do you do with the returned thread objects? Are you keeping a permanent reference to them?

Comment: @ekhumoro
yes, I hold the reference for all threads that were created and started.

Comment: @musicamante I had and still have the same opinion (50%:50%). The problem is it is intermittent. It will disappear by restarting it.  If it comes, it doesn't show the first line of debug message on run() method. I am sure that reading the GPIO or sensor is not the culprit because i have added debug msg before reading and after reading the sensor. And both dont appear when it stucks.

Debug message shows that it leaves move_and start_thread() wo any problem.
  
I will try to provide a minimal reproducible code. It is difficult to reproduce it because it is intermittent.